# How to trust additional certificate with c++ curl?

Tags: c++, curl

I am using the curl library in a C++ project. When testing the https protocol, the ssl handshake fails due to an untrusted certificate. Is there a way to make curl, in addition to its certificate trust policy, also trust the given certificate?

The solution with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is not what I need due to unreliability.

Comment: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html perhaps?

Comment: @RetiredNinja does it add the certificate to the existing ones or override them?